# can't clear ListBox.SelectedItems collection wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I can't clear ListBox.SelectedItems collection. Please suggest what I'm doing wrong.
I clear collection in different ways, but it leave previous collection.

I clear collection so:

```
chListBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

or

```
chListBox.UnselectAll();
```

or

```
chListBox.SetSelectedItems(new ArrayList());
```

My code:

```
public class CheckListBox : ListBox
    {
        public CheckListBox()
        {
            this.SelectionChanged += CheckListBox_SelectionChanged;
            this.Resources = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/TASWpfControls;component/Resources/CheckListBoxResources.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary;
            this.ItemContainerStyle = this.Resources["CheckListBoxItem"] as Style;
            this.AddHandler(ButtonBase.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ClickEventHandler));
        }

        private void ClickEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            RoutedEventArgs eventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ItemSelectedEvent);
            this.RaiseEvent(eventArgs);
        }

        public string PropertyName { get; set; }

        public string PropertyCompare { get; set; }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedSource", typeof(IList), typeof(CheckListBox), new PropertyMetadata(SelectedSourceChanged));

        public IList SelectedSource
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static RoutedEvent ItemSelectedEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ItemSelected", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CheckListBox));

        public event RoutedEventHandler ItemSelected
        {
            add { AddHandler(ItemSelectedEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(ItemSelectedEvent, value); }
        }

        protected static void SelectedSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckListBox chListBox = d as CheckListBox;
            if (chListBox != null)
                chListBox.SortListBox(chListBox, e.NewValue);
        }

        protected virtual void SortListBox(CheckListBox chListBox, object newValue)
        {
            chListBox.SelectedSource = newValue as IList;
            IList selectedItems = chListBox.SelectedSource;
            chListBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
            if (selectedItems != null && selectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (object selectedItem in selectedItems)
                {
                    foreach (object item in chListBox.Items)
                    {
                        if (eIReflector.GetValue(item, chListBox.PropertyName).Equals(eIReflector.GetValue(selectedItem, chListBox.PropertyName)))
                            chListBox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void CheckListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (object addedItem in e.AddedItems)
            {
                if (!SelectedItems.Contains(addedItem))
                    SelectedItems.Add(addedItem);

                if (!SelectedSource.Contains(addedItem))
                    SelectedSource.Add(addedItem);
            }

            foreach (object removedItem in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                this.SelectedItems.Add(removedItem);
                this.SelectedSource.Remove(removedItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using

```
chListBox.ClearSelection(); // For C#
```

and

```
chListBox.UnselectAll(); // For WPF
```

It is working perfect for me...

Comment: Working here as well, .ClearSelection() works flawlessly, Upvoted

Comment: In WPF listBox hasn't method ClearSelection(). Do you know another ways?

Comment: -1. All UnselectAll() does is deselect the selected items in the ListBox. Your answer doesn't work for WPF, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Maybe add a note to the wpf solution informing people of the fact that it will fire a new `SelectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it in WPF doing the following:

```
while(chListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
     chListBox.Items.Remove(chListBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with the following:

```
    var listboxItem = m_listBoxAutocomplete.FindChildElements<ListBoxItem>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsSelected);
    Keyboard.Focus(listboxItem);
```

*However you will need to google FindChildElements extention which is readily available*